# Relation of the words :: 'Thread' and 'Core'

Tags: multithreading, cpu-usage, cpu-cores

Does the number of threads created/able by a program has any relation/constrain with the number or core that CPU has? Does the word `thread` has any relation with `Cores of CPU` at all?

Comment: No.  But it certainly matters if your runtime provides support for a thread pool.  Not uncommon these days.  Your question is *way* too vague to make that a useful avenue for an answer.

Comment: @hans-passant what is thread pool?

Comment: @iamcreasy a Thread Pool is when you spawn multiple threads at once, and assign each one a particular amount of work to do. When it's done, it asks the manager for more work to do, etc. This would be very useful in say... a web server - you don't want to spawn a thread per connection, but rather support a maximum number of connections (the size of the thread pool) and have the pool pick up the connections as they come in. If more connections come in than you have threads, the OS blocks those connections until one is free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A computer can only run number_of_cores threads in parallel. If a system has only a single core, only one thread runs at once. Multitasking is only "simulated" by running each thread consecutively for very short periods of time.

Normally the OS schedules threads arbitrarily on cores. For instance a thread's one quantum could be run on one core and the same thread's next quantum could be run on another core. That's why you see both cores busy when you run a single cpu-heavy thread. This allows single-threaded processes take advantage of multicore systems by distributing load among multiple cores, depending on varying availability.

More than that, operating systems allow a thread to be "locked" on one or more cores, so it runs dedicated on specified cores only. That's called [affinity mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_mask) on Windows. Today's multicore aware software can take advantage of that and dedicate certain threads to certain cores to optimize its workload. Games do that for dedicating AI for one core, rendering for another for instance. In order to do that efficiently the software has to know how many cores a system has and create and assign threads based on that number.

Similarly parallel programming frameworks such as OpenMP count the cores to parallelize operations efficiently. They create as many threads as the number of cores on the system to get optimal performance for physical parallelism.

I think that's the only case of a relation between number of cores and number of threads.

Answer (score 2):

The number of *cores* on a machine is the number of independent processing units that are capable of running at the same time.

The number of *threads* that a program can spawn is the number of logical units of execution that the program would like to run in parallel with each other.

Typically, the number of threads a program can spawn is limited by the language runtime and the operating system's internal threading implementation.  However, if you spawn more threads than there are cores on the machine, not all of those threads can be running in parallel with one another.  Instead, the threads will be scheduled in some fashion to try to maximize the amount of time that each thread is running.  It's fine to have more threads than cores, but you won't necessarily get much of a speedup by introducing new threads once all the cores are running threads at the same time.

In many cases, a program will have many hundreds of threads, only a small number of which will be running at any time.  The other threads might be sleeping and waiting for some event to occur (user input, a timer, a network or disk event, etc.).  This isn't a problem; since those threads aren't actively doing anything, the machine doesn't need to dedicate any cores to them, and can spend its processing power working on other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Each core can execute one thread. If you have X cores, then X threads may execute simultaneously. If you have X cores and X + n threads, then at most X threads will execute simultaneously. However, all threads will execute, as the operating system kernel will share the cores among all of the threads.

Comment: You never took Operating Systems 101, did you?

Comment: I did, and I spawned my own Unix threads, I wrote my own thread scheduler, and all of that jazz. And most of the time, the scheduler will not let you down. But it's not a guarantee, and shouldn't be taken for granted.

Comment: @glowcoder I think this is when thread priority comes in. Unless more then 1 threads has same priority value, there shouldn't not be any problem.

Comment: @iamcreasy Any thread priority you assign is merely a suggestion to the OS. Most often it is ignored to prevent malicious code from trying to lock out other programs. To quote Joshua Bloch, "Any reasonable operating system will try to make this determination fairly, but the policy can very. Therefore, well-written programs shouldn't depend on the details of this policy. **Any program that relies on the thread scheduler for correctness or performance is likely to be nonportable.** (emphasis is the author's)

Comment: @glowcoder What is the perfect/widely accepted solution of this scenario? Like game engines, AI or physics engines, they need to have the correctness.

Comment: @iamcreasy yes they do, but their correctness is not typically defined by what order they finish in. If you need thread A to finish before thread B finishes, then you need to put `a.join()` in thread B. You can't rely on the scheduler to just finish A first. If it works 100% of the time on your testing, but 99.9% of the time on your customer's production box, they're going to have a very difficult bug to track down (if they ever even know it exists!)

Comment: @glowcoder It feels a lot like safety is bigger concern over performance while working on a multicore environment. Isn't it possible to distribute the workload on the hardware level. Say, from outside we see only one core with a wider bus.We pump data in, then the core have 2 cores to work with other then 1. And all the data handling, immutability, locking, unlocking are handled by a control hardware attached with the cpu! Isn't thinking this way makes life easier. Why this is not happening?

Comment: @iamcreasy ummm that would be nice, but threads don't work that way. Either your program is single threaded or it isn't. It is absolutely true that any time you are able to move your workload from requiring multi-threading to a single threaded environment, that you increase safety. When you remove dependency on what order your threads operate in, you greatly increase the reliability of the program. But you can't simply "pump data into a wider bus". That's just not how multithreaded programming works.

Comment: @glowcoder I am reading, [Operating System Concepts](http://www.amazon.com/Operating-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0470128720), but this feels overly broad to me, and talking about a lot of old stuff that I dont need to know. Can you suggest me a more straight forward book for OS. It wont matter if its high level. I want to know more about how the modern operating system works.